# Problema al mostrar una coleccion en Blade

Tags: laravel, blade, colecciones

Tengo una colección que se crea a partir de una matriz en el controlador, así:

```
$this->factura = collect([
    'numero' => '6.218',
    'items' => [
        [
            'cant' => '3',
            'descripcion' => 'Abrazaderas 5x25',
            'precio' => '0,56 €',
            'importe' => '1,68 €',
        ],
        [
            'cant' => '7',
            'descripcion' => 'Argollas 10/48',
            'precio' => '1,13 €',
            'importe' => '7,91 €',
        ],
        [
            'cant' => '1',
            'descripcion' => 'Terminales Mod. Spartan',
            'precio' => '0,27 €',
            'importe' => '0,27 €',
        ],
    ],
    'base' => '9.86 €',
    'iva' => '2.07 €',
    'total' => '11.93 €',
]);
```

Paso la colección a una vista, así:

```
return view('factura')
    ->with([
        'factura' => $this->factura,
    ]);
```

Cuando intento mostrar los datos en Blade, no me los obtiene como propiedades de la colección. En la vista uso esto:

```
{{ $factura->numero }}
```

Y me da un error, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, si en la vista empleo `{{ $factura['numero'] }}` me da el dato sin problemas.

Vamos, que es como si la vista no reconociera la colección como tal, sino como matriz, ignorando el hecho de que sea una colección. Sin embargo, cuando la colección procede de una lectura de base de datos, funciona perfectamente. ¿Hay algún problema con el método `collect()` para convertir una matriz en colección? en la documentación no he encontrado nada al respecto. Estoy usando Laravel 5.8.

He hecho un `dd($this->factura)` en el controlador, y lo muestra como colección, por lo que pienso que, al pasarlo a la vista, debería llegar como tal, no como matriz.

```
Collection {#171 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "numero" => "6.218"
    "items" => array:3 [▶]
    "base" => "9.86 €"
    "iva" => "2.07 €"
    "total" => "11.93 €"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Quieres crear una colección de objetos o simplemente un objeto? Veo que es una sola factura, por eso no me queda claro. Para una colección de objetos a partir de un array puedes: $collection = collect( (object) $array); o para un objeto: $object = (object) $array;

Comment: Ten en cuenta que solo para el caso de un objeto podrás acceder directamente a una de sus propiedades {{ $factura->numero }}. Para el caso de una colección, antes deberás hacer un loop para luego acceder a las propiedades de cada objeto en la colección

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te han apuntado, lo suyo es que la factura sea un objeto, para que puedas acceder a sus propiedades. Pero, dado que la matriz tiene, a su vez submatrices (los que has llamado items), cada una también tiene que ser un objeto. Una forma de hacerlo sería definiendo la matriz en tu controlador así:

```
$this->factura = (object)[
    'numero' => '6.218',
    'items' => [
        (object)[
            'cant' => '3',
            'descripcion' => 'Abrazaderas 5x25',
            'precio' => '0,56 €',
            'importe' => '1,68 €',
        ],
        (object)[
            'cant' => '7',
            'descripcion' => 'Argollas 10/48',
            'precio' => '1,13 €',
            'importe' => '7,91 €',
        ],
        (object)[
            'cant' => '1',
            'descripcion' => 'Terminales Mod. Spartan',
            'precio' => '0,27 €',
            'importe' => '0,27 €',
        ],
    ],
    'base' => '9.86 €',
    'iva' => '2.07 €',
    'total' => '11.93 €',
];
```

Ten en cuenta, ya que lo mencionas, que hay una diferencia entre tu matriz y lo que recuperas de una base de datos cuando haces una consulta. Cuando empleas Eloquent (o el facade DB), lo que obtienes, si es un solo elemento, ya es un objeto, o una colección de objetos, si obtienes más de un resultado, pero ya estás trabajando con elementos que son objetos "per se", no matrices.

Comment: Gracias. Con esa explicación detallada, sí me funciona, y además he comprendido el problema.